# Problem with duplicate images as planes - Strange Black Boxes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, video, duplicate

I am trying to create a stadium scene and am trying to fill the audience with alpha 'animated crowd videos' added as 'image as plane'.  I think it may be a problem with duplicating the video over and over again or maybe them overlapping... but the more I add, when I lower the camera perspective, strange black box shapes emerge upwards from the crowd.  I have included a high shot (where the top of one black box can be seen) and then a lower shot where more black boxes are rising up.  Has anyone got any ideas, it's driving me nuts .  Thanks in advance...  Daniel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think you have a z-fighting problem. Maybe search for that here or via google. You should find answers there. Basically you have to avoid that two planes overlap each other.

Comment: Thanks Chris... do you know if that is for any planes overlapping, ot is it just a problem if they are duplicate frames of the same video?  Thanks

Comment: that's a problem for any object(s). You will have problem rendering "clean" if you have overlapping geometry.